# How to use italic correction for slanted letters (\textsl)?

Tags: italic-correction, slanted

Is there italic correction specific to slanted letters (`\textsl`)? I always use `\textsl` for slanted letters (not `\slshape`), so would redefining `\slshape` to add an `\/` at the end be the easiest way of adding italic correction to slanted letters in my documents?

Comment: i believe that any font that has a slant defined in a `tfm` file will handle an italic correction automatically if accessed in `pdf(la)tex` or the original tex implementation.  things may be different with `xetex` or `luatex`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton as far as I know, xetex does not (when using OpenType fonts) create fake italic corrections from the font data; whereas LuaTeX does, but only for the Italic features. As a result `$\mathrm{f_i^i}\mathit{f_i^i}$` with Latin Modern fonts give different results in the three engines, XeTeX, LuaTeX, and PDFLaTeX (italic corrections are important in math mode).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every letter has an associated italic correction, It is usually non zero for slanted letters. LaTeX automatically inserts `\/` at the start or end of `\textsl` (and all similar commands such as `\textrm`) if the font slope changes from upright to slanted or vice versa.

Comment: I sometimes need to add a small `\hspace{0.5pt}` or `\hspace{1pt}` after `\textsl` when it occurs in section titles. I have a feeling that its appearance in boldface and upright styles is slightly different (when I look in the TOC and in the actual heading, the correction/adjustment seems subtly different), but I cannot prove it.

Comment: The display tittle will use a different font so the italic correction will be different (not necessarily scaled linearly with the font size) You can use `\showoutput` and get a readable representation of the output and see any kerns applied. Sometimes in titles you do need fine tune the spacing for the best effect.